# Rails form for nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

struggling with scopes a little. I have a Profile model which has phone numbers:

```
has_many :phone_contact_infos, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone_contact_infos, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

..then in my PhoneContactInfo model, I have..

```
belongs_to :profile
scope :business,  where('level LIKE ?', 'business')
scope :mobile,    where('level = ?', 'mobile')
```

So basically a profile can have a mobile and a business number. What I've been trying (for a day now) to do is make an edit form for each type (business and mobile) of the phone numbers. This is what I have which does the wrong thing..

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :phone_contact_infos do |contact_info| %>
    <%= contact_info.text_field :country, :size => 2 %>
    <%= contact_info.text_field :city, :size => 5 %>
    <%= contact_info.text_field :number, :size => 8 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

..since I have two database entries (one for mobile and another for business) the above code inserts a form for each type so I end up with text fields for both business and mobile numbers. I just want to edit one number, say mobile. I think I need to make a change in the above code to facilitate the scope defined in the PhoneContactInfo model above.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach.

You could change the `has_many` relationship in your Profile model to include conditions:

```
has_many :mobile_phone_contact_infos, :class_name => "PhoneContactInfo", :conditions => {:level => "mobile"}, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :business_phone_contact_infos, :class_name => "PhoneContactInfo", :conditions => {:level => "business"}, :dependent => :destroy
```

In your view you can then use:

```
<%= f.fields_for :mobile_phone_contact_infos do |contact_info| %>
```

...and it will only pull out the mobile phone contact, not the business numbers.

Two notes:

1. While you can use raw SQL conditions in the `:conditions => {}` clause (eg `where('level LIKE ?', 'business')`), you lose a bit of functionality. In my code above, Rails will intelligently populate the 'level' field for you if you profile.mobile_phone_contact_infos.build - but it won't if you use the raw SQL code.
2. I haven't tested this, and in the past I've only used `:conditions` when the association is polymorphic. I can't confirm whether this is necessary to get your functionality working.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks rob, will try this out.